# Alter final array based on line length

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a textfile with 3 headings like

> ```
> serviceid, jobid, serviceNumber 
> 001, 5, 280
> ```

This stores mechanics jobs for the week. There can only be one jobid/serviceid but there can be more than one service number.

I have a `String[]` which holds the split then assigns these values. But, the trick is some lines have more than one serviceNumber like

> ```
> serviceid, jobid, serviceNumber 
> 002, 8, 250,280,290
> ```

How do I expand my array to hold any extra codes encountered along the way to the `int[]` serviceNumberArray? And, I'm not allowed to use `ArrayList`. Here's my current code:

```
String jobs; //holds extracted textfile values
int jobID;           //holds job id
int serviceID;       //holds service id
int[] serviceNumber; //holds all service numbers

String[] splitJobs = new String[2]; //holds all split jobs
splitJobs = jobs.split(","); //splits jobs and sets delimiter as comma
this.serviceid = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[0]);
this.jobID = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[1]);
this.serviceNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code looks like Java so I'm going to assume that's the answer you need. Then, this

```
String[] splitJobs = new String[2]; // <-- array reference.
```

is deceptive. You throw it away, and you could eliminate that line entirely and you should move your declaration of `serviceNumber`. I think you wanted something like (*note* the regex will remove any whitespace around the commas),

```
// String[] splitJobs = new String[2];
String[] splitJobs = jobs.split("\\s*,\\s*"); // <-- creates a "dynamic" array.
this.serviceid = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[0]);
this.jobID = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[1]);
int[] serviceNumber = new int[splitJobs.length - 2];
for (int i = 2; i < splitJobs.length; i++) {
    this.serviceNumber[i - 2] = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[i]);
}
```

That loop could also be written,

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitJobs.length - 2; i++) {
    this.serviceNumber[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[i + 2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ElliottFrisch i tried the same method but on a textfile with values of {serviceid, name, serviceCodes} and converted them but gives me a numberformat exception for the name?

Comment: @user3680189 Read the first line *the header* (and skip it). You haven't posted that code, but it *might* be simple as `if (line == 0) continue;`

Comment: yes that code is perfect for the first one either loop works well but if one of the fields is a string it will return empty string i do now know why

Comment: Because a String can not be parsed to an Integer. Again, `continue;` on the header.

Comment: sorry isnt there anyway i can use the integer.parseInt(splitPropert[3]) so that by the time it loops through the array its looking of an int not a string? or is that unorthodox?

Comment: `splitJobs[0]` and 1 and 2 are probably `String` as well. Since it's a header record.

Comment: hahah all good @ElliottFrisch thanks for your help i got it as a string then split it , much apppreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String jobs = "1,2,3,4,5,6"; //holds extracted textfile values

    int jobID;           //holds job id
    int serviceID;       //holds service id
    int[] serviceNumber; //holds all service numbers

    String[] splitJobs = jobs.split(","); //splits jobs and sets delimiter as comma

    serviceID = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[0]);

    jobID = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[1]);

    serviceNumber = new int[splitJobs.length - 2];

    for(int i = 2; i < splitJobs.length; i++){
        serviceNumber[i -2] = Integer.parseInt(splitJobs[i]);
    }
  }
```

}

Good Luck !!! Try and give your comments...

Comment: I got the all part of the code from the question and i only add assigning values into the serviceNumber array.

Comment: I run the whole code inside of the main(), that is why i do not use the this key word to access with local variables.